# solve internal error: STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable

Tags: string, gnuplot

Newb here with Gnuplot. I tried just testing it with a simple `plt` script as per below but get the error when using it interactively (there is no output or error message when using it non-interactively). I have tested with `plot sin(x)` interactively and that worked.

The script is as follows:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
set format x "%Y-%m-%d"
set xlabel "Date"
set ylabel "Value"
set title "Decimal Values Over Time"
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with linespoints
```

The input data is a simple 2 columns, space-delimited and the first column is a date and the second column a decimal value.

```
2023-02-01 60
2023-03-01 30
2023-04-01 55
```

I have actually been trying to plot a much more complex file (where it had multiple inputs and decimal values as percentages etc) without success and always having this same error. So I tried this simpler input just to see and still no luck. It's weird that the `plot sin(x)` worked.

I'm now just trying to create a simple line chart with these values over the dates (i.e. dates on *x* and values on *y* and then a line joining each).

I have also done a full upgrade on my system etc.  my Debian is using version Version 5.4 patchlevel 1.

***Edited :*** to add more detail based on the qwuestions below.

1. my plot script is in a file created via vim called `testplot.gnuplot`
2. my data is in a file also created via vim called `data.txt`
   I first executed from the CLI like this `$gnuplot -c testplot.gnuplot`and I saw no output. Then I tried interactive via `$gnuplot` and once in interactive mode, used `load testplot.gnuplot` where I saw the error as per the subject line.

Any ideas on how I can make this work or where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Do your input files contain DOS carriage returns? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings

Comment: I cannot or at least don't know how to reproduce your error. How exactly do you start your gnuplot script? From gnuplot console or from operating console? What is the full command you're typing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the gnuplot console simply put your filename into quotes:

```
load "testplot.gnuplot"
```

Check `help load`:

> ```
> Syntax: 
>
>       load "<input-file>"
>
> The name of the input file must be enclosed in quotes.
> ```

Furthermore:

In the operating system CLI, use the option `-p` for `persistent`, in the  gnuplot-console check `help command line options`. So, something like:

```
gnuplot -p -c Testplot.gnuplot
```

Here, the filename can be with or without quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much, both these tips worked.

Comment: @KingJulian glad to hear. On StackOverflow: "Thank you" or "answer was helpful" = upvote answer, and "answer solved problem" = accept answer (check the check mark at the top left).

Comment: Thanks, done, I could not upvote it due to low post count, but managed to check it.